# Excluding a subdirectory within a subdirectory while making a python wheel package

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am trying to make a python wheel package using setup.py. The folder structure looks like the one mentioned below. (I am using windows 10)

```
D:.
│   setup.py
│  
│   
└───folder_2
    ├───folder_3
    └───folder_4
        ├───folder_5
        └───folder_6
```

Note: setup.py is on the same level as folder_2.

Here, while making a wheel package for folder_2, I want to include the folder_4 but, I do not want to include the folder_5. I only want folder_6.

For folder_5 I want to create a different wheel package in which folder_6 will not be included.

For this, I have tried many methods from the setuptool documentation. None of them seem to work.

The program that I am using right now is also given below.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name="example",
             version="0.1.0",
             packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="folder_2",
                                       exclude=['folder_4.folder_5']),
             package_dir={"": "folder_2"},
             include_package_data=True
             )
```

I have also tried to use *include()* instead of *exclude()*.

Can someone please help me with this?

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(name="example",
             version="0.1.0",
             packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="folder_2",
                                       exclude=['folder_4.folder_5']),
             package_dir={"": "folder_2"},
             include_package_data=True
             )
```

Comment: "_None of them seem to work._", how so? I would recommend you to edit the question to show explicitly what is the unexpected result in each case you have tried (probably a good way is to show the list of files contained in the sdist and the wheel).

Comment: Note that you can also debug yourself. Try to print out different combinations of `find_packages`, for example: `python -c "import setuptools; print(setuptools.find_packages(where='folder2', exclude=['folder4.folder5']))"`.

Comment: Hello @sinoroc, what I mean by "none of them seem to work" is, no matter if I try to exclude or include the folders, all folders under folder_2 directory are always included in my wheel package even if I don't want them to.

Comment: Maybe you need to also exclude `folder4.folder5.*`. Maybe you need to clean up everything (`build` and `dist`) before trying again.

Comment: When I print the list of folders with setuptool.find_packages() like you suggested, I am seeing the right folders included there. I tried with the folder4.folder5.* it did not work. Is it possible that the files in the folder_4 have dependencies on the files in folder_5. That is why the folder_5 is included by default?

Comment: I checked in file, there is no dependency between the individual files in each folder.

Comment: I also tried making an .egg file with sdist but that is also not helpful. Because unwanted folders are included in that as well.

Comment: But do these unwanted packages and modules actually get installed? In other words: are they in the wheel? -- Also you could try by excluding/pruning via the `MANIFEST.in` file.

Comment: yes, they are getting installed. I can import their contents in python using python import. And I checked the contents of the wheel packages by converting it to a .zip file. The folders are there. I have not tried using MANIFEST.in can you please send a link of the documentation or someting? I will meanwhile search on the internet.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/

Comment: I read the documentation yersterday. It is helpful for making a .tar file. But not that helpful while making a wheel package.  I also noticed one interesting thing. That the wheel packages for the folder_5 and folder_6 (even when created and installed separately) are somehow related in the background. Because when I uninstall one using pip, the contents of the second folder are also removed from the site packages.

Comment: Are folder5 and folder6 supposed to be separate projects? Are they supposed to be separately installable? Do they have their own `setup.py`?